# suppressMessages with a return instead of a print in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, suppressmessage

I have a package that has a bunch of functions that generate ggplot2 objects. Recently, ggplot2 added an update that gives a message that says:

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

I know why ggplot2 is saying that, but I don't need to hear it *every* time I run a plot (and it confuses my users because they think they did something wrong). I know I can suppress the messages by wrapping a print statement in `suppressMessages` but I don't want to `print` a plot, I want to `return` it. If I `print` it, it will display the plot, even when I don't want to display it.

Any ideas? Here's a minimum working example.

```
f = function(y,x,data){
    p = ggplot(data, aes_string(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(se=F)
    #suppressMessages(return(p))    ### doesn't work
    suppressMessages(print(p))      ### works, but I don't want to PRINT it
}
data(iris)
head(iris)
f("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", iris)
```

Comment: Maybe set `method = 'loess'` instead of the default?

Comment: the message just changes to something shorter.

Comment: The message is generated only when the plot is plotted, so you could wrap `suppressMessages` around your call to `f`. Notably - the warning won't appear if you assign the result of `f` (i.e., it's not implicitly printing)

Comment: Sorry, the message is still there, even with method="loess" when se=F.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just set `method = 'loess'` instead of `method = 'auto'`, which is the default:

```r
library(ggplot2)
f = function(y,x,data){
  p = ggplot(data, aes_string(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "loess")
  return(p)
}

data(iris)

gg <- f("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", iris)
gg
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't see a message here, not even a short one.

The other option is to define a custom print function and give your output object a different class:

```r
f = function(y,x,data){
  p = ggplot(data, aes_string(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
  class(p) <- c("gg_silent", class(p))
  return(p)
}

print.gg_silent <- function(gg) {
  suppressMessages(ggplot2:::print.ggplot(gg))
}
```

This will suppress the messages when the returned object is printed. Since this adds a class rather than overwrite the old one, you can still add arguments with `+` without a problem. Still I would say that the first option should be the better one.

Comment: That new method is a brilliant solution!

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of ggplot2, but current ggplot2 still prints a message: "`geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'". If you don't want to have this message, you need to pass the argument `fromula = y ~ x`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r#L87), `stat_smooth` and `geom_smooth` will print messages unless both `method` and `formula` are given as arguments (furthermore, `method` should not be `"auto"`).  If you use `method = "loess"`, then most likely you want `formula = y ~ x`.  So the following should work silently:

```r
f = function(y,x,data){
    ggplot(data, aes_string(x,y)) + geom_point() +
        geom_smooth(se=F, method = "loess", formula = y ~ x)
}
data(iris)
head(iris)
f("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", iris)
```

(I also removed the extra assignment and the explicit return statements, but that's a matter of taste.)